# Verilog bit metadata

Tags: metadata, verilog

is there a way to easily add a Metadata to a verilog bit? My goal is to be able to identify certain bits that are well known prior to encryption, after an ethernet frame is being encrypted. I'd like to easily identify these bits location in the encrypted frame. I'd like this Metadata to be transparent to the actual design rtl (i.e. Allow it to flow naturally through external IPs that are not mine, and be recovered and analyzed on the other end).
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. The idea of  encryption is the data after encryption should show no relation to the data before encryption. If not the encryption could easily be broken.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I wasn't clear. The idea is to have this info only for verification purpose. It's as if I'm sending 2 bits instead of 1 in parallel, one going through encryption, the other goes through unchanged. But I want to do it in line, in the original path through external "black box" IPs, and extract the additional bit ("Metadata") on the other end

Comment: I don't want this to be synthesized in any way the additional info should only exist in rtl verification environment

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to do this using the original RTL path.

You were not clear about your reasoning for this, but sometimes people use a *watermark* which is encoding something into your data which is inconsequential to the design, but has meaning to your verification environment. For example, instead of sending completely random data in a packet, you send data with a specific checksum that has meaning to your verification environment.

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe using SV class to wrap a bit to a more complex data struct, but reduce it for a bit for the actual design processing (casting? something like that...). so actually only using the class structure on the other end. and maybe remove it from synthesis using ifdef. very high level concept, don't know if feasible in verilog/SV. as for using a fixed pattern, that's a good idea I'll consider, though not as flexible...

Comment: Then you are no longer following your stated requirement of flowing through the RTL. You can always add metadata to expected results and match that up with the actual results.

Comment: Thanks Dave, you're right. this is why I do want the metadata option. So I didn't understand the comment "You can always add metadata to expected results" - so how can I add it to the data stream?

Comment: Your testbench supposedly generates two streams of data; one as input to your DUT, and another as the expected output of your DUT. You can add whatever information you want to the input stream and p[ass that along to the component that predicts the output. Without a clearer picture of what this _metadata_ is, it will be hard to help you further.